# Set tty1 as default

Tags: linux, terminal, boot, tty

Here are the details of my system:

> vinoth@vinoth:~$ uname -a
>   Linux vinoth 3.2.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.2.63-2+deb7u1 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

When my system boots, I am getting tty7(GUI) by default. How to change the default tty?

Comment: Change your default runlevel from 5 to 2 in /etc/inittab

Comment: Do you want to boot to a console e.g. tty1 or do you want to boot into a graphical desktop, but then not tty7? For the former see http://askubuntu.com/q/16371/425630

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not clear. 
Do you want to switch to tty1 from tty7. 
To do that press Ctrl+Alt+F1. This will take you to tty1.

Ctrl+Alt+F1 - tty1
Ctrl+Alt+F2 - tty2
Ctrl+Alt+F3 - tty3
Ctrl+Alt+F4 - tty4
Ctrl+Alt+F5 - tty5
Ctrl+Alt+F6 - tty6
Ctrl+Alt+F7 - tty7


If you want your system to boot direcctly to tty1 then you need to change the default runlevel to 1 in /etc/inittab.

Answer (score 1):

The X graphics server would fail to start up if it was not running on the current tty.  (And the same for common wayland compositors).  In some circumstances the X server will switch the current tty as required when it starts up.  In others, it requires the current tty to be set correctly before it is started. There is no current way to delay the start of the X server until you first switch to tty7.  Therefore you cannot both start the GUI on tty7, and boot to tty1.

(Consistent with this, I have sometimes noticed the graphics startup can fail if I use ctrl+alt+Fx to switch tty too soon, before it has finished setting up).

Note that when you upgrade from Debian 7 to Debian 8 or Debian 9, which use `systemd` by default, the GNOME GUI will now start on tty1 :-).